# Merge memorystreams to one iText document

Tags: c#-4.0, merge, itext, memorystream

I have four MemoryStreams of data that I want to merge and then open the pdfDocument, without creating a single file.

It's possible to write them down to files and then merge them but that would be bad practice and that can also cause a few issues so I want to avoid that.

However, I can not find a way to merge the MemoryStreams with iText5 for .NET.

Right now, this is how I do it with files:

```
    private static void ConcatenateDocuments()
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();

        var readerFrontPage = new PdfReader(Folder + FrontPageName);
        var readerDocA = new PdfReader(Folder + docA);
        var readerDocB = new PdfReader(Folder + DocB);
        var readerAppendix = new PdfReader(Folder + Appendix);
        var pdfCopyFields = new PdfCopyFields(stream);

        pdfCopyFields.AddDocument(readerFrontPage);
        pdfCopyFields.AddDocument(readerDocA );
        pdfCopyFields.AddDocument(readerDocB);
        pdfCopyFields.AddDocument(readerAppendix);
        pdfCopyFields.Close();

        SavePdf(stream, FilenameReport);
    }
```

Since I need to remove the use of files, I keep the MemoryStream's as the different parts are built from different resources. So I have references to these memorystreams.

How can this be done?

Comment: Can't you use var readerFrontPage = new PdfReader(yourMemoryStream);

Comment: That's the thing, I can not get that working. One of the errors I run into is "PDF header signature not found". Most people that runs into this problem uses files however, and that's not an option here.

Comment: While it seams the PdfReader can not take the stream, the array of the stream works.

var readerFrontPage = new PdfReader(streamFrontPage.ToArray()); Thou I can not answer my own question yet...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The error `PDF header signature not found` can be fixed in this case by setting the stream's `Position` back to `0`. Since you're not getting the error `Cannot access a closed Stream` I'm assuming that you are already correctly setting the `PdfWriter`'s `CloseStream` to `false`.

Below is a full working C# 2010 WinForm app targeting iTextSharp 5.1.1.0 that creates three PDFs in `MemoryStreams` and combines them. Since I don't have a web server handy I'm writing them to disk.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Create three MemoryStreams
            MemoryStream[] streams = { CreateDoc("Page 1"), CreateDoc("Page 2"), CreateDoc("Page 3") };

            //I don't have a web server handy so I'm going to write my final MemoryStream to a byte array and then to disk
            byte[] bytes;

            //Create our final combined MemoryStream
            using (MemoryStream finalStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //Create our copy object
                PdfCopyFields copy = new PdfCopyFields(finalStream);

                //Loop through each MemoryStream
                foreach (MemoryStream ms in streams)
                {
                    //Reset the position back to zero
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    //Add it to the copy object
                    copy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(ms));
                    //Clean up
                    ms.Dispose();
                }
                //Close the copy object
                copy.Close();

                //Get the raw bytes to save to disk
                bytes = finalStream.ToArray();
            }

            //Write out the file to the desktop
            string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Combined.pdf");
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);   
            }

            this.Close();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper method to create temporary documents
        /// </summary>
        private MemoryStream CreateDoc(string name)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
            {
                using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    writer.CloseStream = false;
                    doc.Open();
                    doc.Add(new Paragraph(name));
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
            return ms;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. In my case I was doing `stream.Position = 0` but in the wrong place: inside the `using` statement. After moving it outside it works great. By the way Chris: congrats for helping the community when it comes to iTextSharp. God bless you! :)

Comment: Thanks, working for me when remembering to set CloseStream to false on writer and call close document before using stream.

Comment: How would you open the pdf rather than saving to the desktop in your example?

Comment: @Standage, are you using a webserver? If so you could [just write the bytes out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13473931/231316). If you are on a desktop you can write the bytes out and call `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` on the file and as long as there is a handler registered it should open. It is very important to note that iTextSharp is in no way a PDF renderer or viewer. If you want to actually "look" at a PDF you'll need a program like Adobe Reader.

Comment: I think most users have Adobe reader these days? I got my deisred results by passing the finalStream into a new method and using 'Response.OutputStream', thanks

Comment: I would say less people (as a percentage) have Adobe Reader installed these days compared to just a couple of years ago. Mac OSX has had Preview for years which can read PDFs and Windows 8 shipped with a built-in one, too. All major modern web browsers also ship with a native PDF renderer, too. I still find it funny whenever I see a website that uses the "Adobe Reader" icon to signify a PDF. But if you just mean that most people have a PDF renderer of some sort installed, not necessarily Adobe's, I think I'd agree with that.

Comment: Chris, I used your solution Today in my application and it worked wonders for me ....

Answer (score 0):

While it seams the PdfReader can not take the stream, the array of the stream works.

var readerFrontPage = new PdfReader(streamFrontPage.ToArray());