# How to control multiple connections in ASP.NET web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, concurrency

I have web page index.aspx and corresponding server side code index.aspx.cs. This C# code has a method which cannot executed in parallel if multiple clients connect to my website. How can I restrict this?

Here is what the method does. It creates a folder, zip it and make it available for the user to download. My requirement is that when one user is executing this method, some other user should not do this because it will create the same folder again which leads to corruption of data.

I tried using Session objects. But I came to know that session objects are stored per client basis.

Can anyone suggest me some solution?

Comment: You need to rethink your problem. Do all users want same zipped file? If not then, you should create (random folders maybe) folders and keep a reference of folder name in your calling code. Instead of session, use Cache to store limiting variable if you don't want to change how zipped files are created.

Comment: All users don't want same zipped file. Based on the user selections on the UI, the package differs.

Comment: @RaviChandra why not defer creation of the zip until they try to download it, and just do it in-memory? no contention then, and no wasted effort

Comment: WHy not give each file a unique name? Simplest is GUID.

Answer (score 1):

The Application context or a static class is application wide. So you can store a flag which indicates that the process is already started. After the procees ended, you can delete the flag.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf(v=vs.100).aspx

And always use `Application.Lock` when you write to the application state and `lock(mutex)` when you use a static class.

In your case a static class would be a better solution, because it seems that the application context exist only for compatible purposes to classic asp: [Using static variables instead of Application state in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960695/using-static-variables-instead-of-application-state-in-asp-net/10964038#10964038)

```
static object mutex= new object();

lock(mutex)
{
   //Do the work
}
```

Comment: The application context is nothing more than static variables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960695/using-static-variables-instead-of-application-state-in-asp-net/10964038#10964038

Comment: Kai, Thanks for your answer, this will help solving my problem

Answer (score 1):

My immediate advice would be: create a random folder name per request, which would *allow* you to run them concurrently. However, if that isn't an option then you will need to synchronize using something like `lock` or `Mutex`. However, this would only work well if you are returning the result *from the current request*, rather than zipping it in one request, and letting them download it the next.

Frankly, though, I think that you should do the zip *in the request for the zip*. Indeed, unless the file will be huge you don't even need to touch the file-system - you can create a zip in-memory using `MemoryStream` and any of the zip encoders (`System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage` for example) - then just hand the client the data from the `MemoryStream`.

If you are using MVC, this is just `return File(contents, contentType)`. With vanilla ASP.NET you need a [few more steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13473931/23354).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the classic asp.net session you do not need to do anything because session all ready lock the run of the pages from multiple users.

If you not, then you can follow what Marc suggest, use `Mutex`.

About the session lock:
[Web app blocked while processing another web app on sharing same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426673/web-app-blocked-while-processing-another-web-app-on-sharing-same-session)
[jQuery Ajax calls to web service seem to be synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052401/jquery-ajax-calls-to-web-service-seem-to-be-synchronous)
[ASP.NET Server does not process pages asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284530/asp-net-server-does-not-process-pages-asynchronously)
[Replacing ASP.Net's session entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989648/replacing-asp-nets-session-entirely)

Comment: session does *not* block multiple runs of the page at the same time (certainly not for different users, but usually not for the same user either); asp.net is inherently happy to run multiple copies of the same page

Comment: @MarcGravell Maybe I did not write it correct ? Is lock them and is not going to run the code in parallel, if the code is from inside call of the page.